# CREATE EDUCATIONCLASS TEAMS ERROR - Team Definition. Visibility' should be equal to 'HiddenMembership'

Tags: api, graph

When I want to create a team with EducationClass template, I get an error like this. I have not been receiving such an error before. All the same. what could be the problem?

```
 {
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Failed to execute Templates backend request CreateTeamFromTemplateRequest. Request Url: https://teams.microsoft.com/fabric/emea/templates/api/team, Request Method: POST, Response Status Code: BadRequest, Response Headers: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000\r\nx-operationid: 2230c436382c754aadfda14e58e7b308\r\nx-telemetryid: 00-2230c436382c754aadfda14e58e7b308-ae2a19a55b3ea34c-00\r\nX-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: CA7D2D550A204688B37F03E163F4E43C Ref B: LON21EDGE1213 Ref C: 2020-11-23T07:20:16Z\r\nDate: Mon, 23 Nov 2020 07:20:16 GMT\r\n, ErrorMessage : {\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"'Team Definition. Visibility' should be equal to 'HiddenMembership'.\"}],\"operationId\":\"2230c436382c754aadfda14e58e7b308\"}",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-11-23T07:20:17",
            "request-id": "c67774cf-b900-4b77-9850-26f40b82e9b4",
            "client-request-id": "c67774cf-b900-4b77-9850-26f40b82e9b4"
        }
    }
}

POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams

{
 "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('educationClass')",
  "displayName": "My Class Team",
  "description": "My Class Team’s Description"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they made a breaking change in the beta version, try using v1.0 and make the request in the following way:

```html
{
"template@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('educationClass')", 
  "displayName":"My Sample Team",
  "description":"My Sample Team’s Description", 
  "members":[ 
      { 
       "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
       "roles":["owner"], 
       "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')" 
      }
   ] 
}
```